# PHP REgEx preg_replace first folder name (wildcard)

Tags: php, regex, wildcard

Having regex issues..

I have a series of directories that hold .htm templates... all template packs are held in folder tpl/ (not really that important)

tpl contains a default template pack called tpl_default.

I am writing a function that reads from the current template file and then gets all Tokens {TOKEN} from the same file in the default directory.

```
// $file returns abundant/index/index.htm as an example. So need to change that to read tpl_default/index/index.htm
$file = preg_replace('/?WHAT/','tpl_default',$file); // loose the first directory and replace with the default dir....
$default_file = file_get_contents("../../tpl/".$file);
// read the default template and pull all the tokens....
$subject = $default_file;
$pattern = "/{.*?}/";                                       
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
return $matches; // TODO: convert matches to <li> element
```

Having issues with the regex "?WHAT" in line 1 really. Each time the first directory might be something different, so how do I match ONLY the first directory with a wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `^` anchor so that `preg_replace()` replaces only the first directory. And you did not give an example of a representative file path. (Does it begin with a leading `/` or possibly `//`?) In either case, this should do the trick:

```php
$file = preg_replace('%^(/*)[^/]+%','$1tpl_default',$file);
```

Comment: Excelent! Yes you are quite right, it needs to find the first dir only, FYI i did include an example of the file path in the code.. // $file returns abundant/index/index.htm as an example. So need to change that to read tpl_default/index/index.htm
  This one works like a charm though - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex, I think that's it

```
'\/[\w\s_-]+\/'
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Also, the `_` in the character class is needless since the `\w` covers that character.  I don't know why you are escaping your pattern delimiters either.

Answer (score 0):

solution is:

```
$pattern1 = "%^(/*)[^/]+%";
$default_file = preg_replace($pattern1,'tpl_default',$file); // loose the first 
$default_file = file_get_contents("../../tpl/".$default_file);
$subject = $default_file;
$pattern = '/\{.*?\}/';                                        
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
return $matches;
```

Thanks goes to ridgerunner for the solution

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.